# How to create clickhouse udf c++ function

Tags: clickhouse

Clickhouse UDF doesn't work

I have create simple c++ function

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ 
  std::cout<<42;
  return 0;
}
```

and config in clickhouse

```
 <functions>
     <function>
         <type>executable</type>
         <name>testA</name>
         <return_type>UInt64</return_type>
         <format>TabSeparated</format>
         <command>./test</command>
     </function>
 </functions>
```

but when I run it like: `select * testA();` I get:

```
Code: 1. DB::Exception: Function 'testA': wrong result, expected 1 row(s), actual 0: while executing 'FUNCTION testA() -> testA() UInt64 : 0'. (UNSUPPORTED_METHOD) (version 22.2.2.1)
```

I didn't find any working examples of C++ udf for clickhouse, so if anyone can help me to run this fucntion or share working example of C++ udf fucntion I would really appreciate that

Comment: Your function shall return value to stdout for each input string which you read from stdin

Answer (score 0):

Your function shall return value to stdout for each input value which you read and parse from stdin

look python examples in https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/udf

Answer (score 0):

The C++ code is okay and since the error indicates that ClickHouse was able to call the compiled binary I assume that the configuration of UDFs in ClickHouse's configuration file is also good.

I actually tried the example locally, and it worked for me. I was using `<return_type>String</return_type>` but it did not make a difference here.

PS: Suggest to update your clickhouse binary, v22.2 is rather old.